# Show that $\diamond(p,q,r)$ is complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I`m trying to show that $\{\diamond\}$ is complete.

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
P&Q&R&\diamond(P,Q,R)\\
\hline
T&T&T&F\\
T&T&F&F\\
T&F&T&F\\
T&F&F&T\\
F&T&T&T\\
F&T&F&T\\
F&F&T&T\\
F&F&F&T\\
\end{array}

I know that $\{\vee, \neg \}$ is complete.

Then, if we show NOT & OR by $\diamond$ we done.

NOT is easy: $\neg p \Longleftrightarrow \diamond(p,p,p)$

---

However,is it correct to use T\F to show $p \vee q$, since I don`t know how is it possible to show it without T\F.

Thats is what I wrote:
$p\vee q \Longleftrightarrow \neg(\diamond(T,p,q))$ is this correct?

What the right way to think about it when I need to show if is complete? It took my a lot of time to get to it and I not succeed to write it without using T or F.

Comment: It would help if you would write the definition of "complete".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's permissible to use $T$ and $F$ depends on your definition of "complete". See the discussion on the Wikipedia page for [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Formal_definition). But in this case, we don't have to use them: The term $\diamond(\lnot p,p,p)$ is always $T$.

Putting this together with your observations, we can define $p\lor q$ by  $$\lnot(\diamond(\diamond(\lnot p, p,p),p,q)).$$

Comment: This is great! This is exactly what I looking for.

Comment: The reasoning was a simple search: I hoped to find a term using $\lnot$ and $\diamond$ in one variable with constant truth value. I started looking at the simplest kind of terms like this: $\diamond$ applied to three inputs, each of which is $p$ or $\lnot p$. So I looked at the table: e.g. $\diamond(p,p,p)$ is the first row and last row, depending on the truth value of $p$. $\diamond(p,p,\lnot p)$ is the second row and the second-to-last row, depending on the truth value of $p$. My definition $\diamond(\lnot p,p,p)$ is the fourth and fifth rows, which both have value $T$. Jackpot!